# Boost.Numpy installed from source but is not working

Tags: libraries, boost

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and I have `libboost-all-dev` installed (Boost 1.54) and I need to install the Boost.NumPy library.

I know that NumPy comes with Boost 1.64+ but I need to stick with 1.54 for now, and hence I need to installed from [this](https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy) repo which is currently deprecated.

I followed the instructions under [`Boost.NumPy/libs/numpy/doc/cmakeBuild.rst`](https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy/blob/master/libs/numpy/doc/cmakeBuild.rst). These instructions are:

1. mkdir build
2. cd build
3. cmake ..
4. make
5. sudo make install

All good, I don't get any errors during these commands, so I assume that Boost.Numpy was installed successfully on my system.

I tried to compile a simple C++ program to check if the system can find the file but it is not working.

The C++ file just contains the following header:

```
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
```

I then compile like this:

```
g++ test.cpp
```

I get the error:

```
test.cpp:1:34: fatal error: boost/python/numpy.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
                                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

I tried to search for the header file and I can see that is there.

```
$ sudo find / -name "numpy.hpp"
/usr/local/include/boost/numpy.hpp
```

I have also added the following in my `.bashrc` file:

```
export INCLUDE="/usr/local/include/boost:$INCLUDE"
export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/include/boost:$LIBRARY_PATH"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/boost"
```

Still nothing.

So why is Boost.Numpy not installed properly? What do I miss? The documentation is quite minimal and I couldn't find anything else around.

And in general, how can I find out if a Boost library I have installed is available to the system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're including the header as

```
<boost/python/numpy.hpp>
```

it expects to find `numpy.hpp` in a subdirectory `python` of a directory `boost` somewhere on either the default include file search path, or a path supplied to the compiler via the `-I` option

However, the file is actually at

```
/usr/local/include/boost/numpy.hpp
```

with no `python` subdirectory - so you should include it in your C++ file as just

```
#include <boost/numpy.hpp>
```

and then telling `g++` to add `/usr/local` to the include file search path

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include test.cpp
```