# Boost installed via Boost.Numpy not compatible with newer version

Tags: boost

I have installed [Boost.Numpy](https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy) on Boost 1.54 (`libboost-all-dev`) on Ubuntu 14.04.

This version of Numpy installs the library in a structure that you can invoke it like this in C++:

```
#include <boost/numpy.hpp>
```

Newer version of Boost (i.e., Boost 1.64+) which comes with Numpy preinstalled, uses a different structure that has the format of:

```
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
```

It seems that having [Boost.Numpy](https://github.com/ndarray/Boost.NumPy) on Boost 1.58 is not compatible with code that assumes Numpy is installed through a newer version of Boost (i.e., `boost/python/numpy.hpp`).

I have some code, let's say package A, (that for some reason does not work with Boost 1.64) that uses Boost 1.54 and some other software, let's say package B, that I build from source that requires Boost with Numpy (and their code assume `boost/python/numpy.hpp`).

I would like to make this two compatible so I can only think of two solutions:

1. Modify every code in the package B and change the definition `#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>` to become `<#include <boost/numpy.hpp>` (although I am not sure if this will fix 100% the problem)
2. Move all the Numpy files from my system from where they are to `boost/python` so they are compatible with package B (since package A does not need Numpy).

I am not sure if the two solutions will be appropriate or if there is a better way to do this? I am currently on a clean install and I don't want to break anything.

Unfortunately, I also tried to build package B with Boost 1.64 and package A with Boost 1.54 but the two are talking to each other and I found out that having the two with different Boost versions causes segmentation fault, so I definitely need to avoid this solution.

Comment: I do not have 14.04 LTS to test your approach. But I see that 18.04 LTS has this [functionality out-the-box](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=numpy.hpp). Do you plan to upgrade the Ubuntu to 18.04 LTS? It would be hassle-free solution.

Comment: @N0rbert You are right. Unfortunately, this is not an option, I am working with a specific stack of software that are currently working perfectly only with 14.04.

Comment: With reference to your previous question [Boost.Numpy installed from source but is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058218/boost-numpy-installed-from-source-but-is-not-working) are you sure the issue is not that you are linking your software against the "wrong" libboost? (The accepted answer there would only address location of the correct headers, during the compilation phase - you likely need to use a `-L` directive to make sure it links against the *libraries* in /usr/local/lib).

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your point, but I don't think so, the code I am trying to compile has some files in `src/` that have includes `<#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>`.

Comment: @John is the thing you are trying to compile an executable program or a shared library? do you understand the difference between *compiling* and *linking*? if it's an executable, then what boost numpy library to you see if you run `ldd` on the executable after building it (in particular, is it the one in `/usr/local` or one in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` for example?)

Comment: It is a shared library. I use `cmake` and `make`. I thought this is compiling?

Answer (score 1):

As you do not want to upgrade to 18.04 LTS, so let's stay on 14.04 LTS.
But create Ubuntu 18.04 LTS [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) in it with new Boost here:

```
sudo apt-get install schroot debootstrap -y

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/schroot/chroot.d/bionic.conf
[bionic]
description=Ubuntu 18.04
directory=/srv/chroot/bionic
root-users=$USER
type=directory
users=$USER
EOF

sudo mkdir -p /srv/chroot/bionic
sudo debootstrap bionic /srv/chroot/bionic

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /srv/chroot/bionic/etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

schroot -c bionic -u root apt-get update
schroot -c bionic -u root apt-get install software-properties-common sudo
schroot -c bionic -u root apt-get install libboost1.65-dev
```

Do not forget to change root to this chroot when you want to compile Boost-NumPy stuff:

```
schroot -c bionic
```

After this command the command prompt will change from `user@host:~$` to `(bionic)user@host:~$` and you can run compilation inside this shell.

I previously tested this method with other applications.
Currently I have 12.04 LTS (now EOL) schroot inside my 16.04 LTS for some development tasks.

Comment: That is amazing! Is that possible? Let me try it on my VM and I will get back to you. (it will take a while)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do not forget to make snapshot (if it is production VM) :)

Comment: Will this require though to enter `schroot -c bionic` when I want to run the compiled code? Or the code will be compiled on my 14.04?

Comment: You need to enter to this new virtual environment with `schroot -c bionic` to have 18.04 LTS tools working. Also you can try to change directory to the code (for example `~/code` - `cd ~/code`) and then run `schroot -c bionic make` here.

Comment: That is a small problem, because the library I would like to compile with libboost1.65 needs to talk with other libraries that are installed on 14.04

Comment: Then you can try to install these libraries to 18.04 chroot with `schroot -c bionic -u root apt-get install library-package-name`.

Comment: I see. I don't think this will work, because these libraries are only available on 14.04 and compiled from source (robotics software mess)

Comment: There are to many constrains :) But I have no more ideas.

Comment: I know. Thanks so much for your time though! This `schroot` thing is really useful in general!